# How can I set width of vaadin layout and still have inner components take as much space as they need?

Tags: java, css, sass, vaadin, vaadin8

So I have an object of `VerticalLayout`.
Without height being set - inner components look fine: each label takes as least space as it can and stays on top:

[image: example with no height]

But, if I set height of layout to 400px with `filesLayout.setHeight("400px");` - each of my 3 labels starts taking 33% of the space :

[image: example with height]

I just want my labels to take only required amount of space and my VerticalLayout to be as long as I set it to be. Please, help me.

Comment: should all components keep the same size (i.e. would you mind if only the last one get expanded)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `VerticalLayout` distributes the heights equally between all components.
So with 3 components, you get 3 rows, each 33% of the full `VerticalLayout` height.

You can manipulate the expand ratios with the `.setExpandRatio(...)`

To have all `Labels`on top, you just need to add a "empty" `Label`als last element to the `VerticalLayout`, and tell the `VerticalLayout`to use all "overflow" height to this last line.

```
Label empty= new Label();
vl.addComponent(empty);
vl.setExpandRatio(empty, 1);
```

Setting it to 1 means that it will take 1 part of the overflow height.

There is also this short cut method to do both in one call:

```
vl.addComponentsAndExpand(empty);
```

This is the answer to your question, but probably you will comme up with this issue:

What do we do when the content of the VerticalLayout is higher than the available height?
But that's another question, perhaps a Panel would be the better container if you wish to have scroll bars.

Comment: That's one dirty workaround. But it works. Thank you very much. P.S. It's "setExpandRatio", not "setComponentExpandRatio".

Comment: A small improvement (use instead of the code above): Label empty= new Label();
vl.addComponentAndExpand(empty);